# Распарсить JSON

Tags: xml, angularjs, jsonp

**Есть json** http://select.by/courses/converter/server_calc.php?date=0

```
$http.jsonp('http://select.by/courses/converter/server_calc.php?date=0')
  .then(function(json) {
      $scope.bank = json.data;
});
```

Содержимое запроса

```
{
  "var_usd": 19996,
  "var_eur": 22781,
  "var_rur": 297.86
}
```

Получаю ошибку: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**

я так понимаю не верный формат json, не хватает [], как быть? В моём случае мне надо только оттуда получить:

*19996*

**или есть ещё XML http://www.nbrb.by/Services/XmlExRates.aspx**

Нужно получить курс любого рубля, какие есть варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В jsonp предполагается передача на сервер имени `callback` функции.
По канонам жанра jsonp добавляет на страницу скрипт с помощью тэга

```
<script scr="http://select.by/courses/converter/server_calc.php?date=0"></script>
```

Он сразу же автоматически запускается браузером. Предполагается что там будет вызов функции `callback` с объектом json в качестве параметра.

Вообще говоря, сервер может заслать любой скрипт и он будет выполнен. Если это не правильный скрипт, с ошибками, то естественно выполнение приведёт к ошибке.

В Вашем запросе этого параметра `callback` не наблюдается (не может же им быть data=0). Возможно поэтому сервер возвращается json без обёртки в функцию, не правильный скрипт.

Запрос должен быть типа такого `http://select.by/courses/converter/server_calc.php?date=0&callback=JSON_CALLBAC‌​K`

`JSON_CALLBACK` - это какая-то встроенная функция $http. В документации так и написано, что надо указывать именно её.

Вместо `callback` может быть другое название. Надо уточнить у хозяина сервиса.

А если хозяин такой, что не следует канонам, тогда применяйте методы для работы с обычным `JSON`, а не `JSONP`. (например $http.get и полученный текст в парсер json)

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете метод **jsonp**, который ожидает что по url будет возвращен валидный javascript код, к примеру:

```
foo({
    "var_usd": 20206,
    "var_eur": 23002,
    "var_rur": 294.21
});
```

А по http://select.by/courses/converter/server_calc.php?date=0 возвращается только валидный json объект.

В большинстве случаев по причине Cross-domain политики, загрузить данные в браузере с другого домена не удастся. Варианты - искать источник, позволяющий Cross-domain запросы (есть платные предложения), либо собирать информацию сначала на своем сервере (например скриптом по крону), и раздавать уже со своего домена.